# want to delete star and the char in front and follow it, why my code does not work

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Return a version of the given string, where for every star (*) in the string the star and the chars immediately to its left and right are gone. So "ab*cd" yields "ad" and "ab**cd" also yields "ad". It is a coding bat problem.

```
public class DeleteStar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s=deleteS("ab*ab");
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static String deleteS(String s)
    { 
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));     
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        for (int i=0;i<sb.length();i++) 
        { 
            if (sb.charAt(i)+""=="*")
            {
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                sb.deleteCharAt(i-1);
                sb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Make sure to not delete stars that are adjacent to other stars.  2) make sure to decrement `i` appropriately when deleting entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete a character, you also shorten the length of the string by 1. So if you call your sequence on "ab*cd", suppose we know `i = 2`, we'll get:

```
sb.deleteCharAt(i); // We now have "abcd"
sb.deleteCharAt(i-1); // We now have "acd"
sb.deleteCharAt(i+1); // Oops! "acd" has no index of 3!
```

But even if we've done the above correctly, if we have two adjacent stars, this will create problems. So we should check whether the adjacent characters are stars or not before we delete. For instance, if we run this on "ab**cd", we'll get:

```
// This is the correct way if no stars are adjacent to each other.
// But if there are? Testing on "ab**cd"
sb.deleteCharAt(i-1); // We now have "a**cd"
sb.deleteCharAt(i-1); // We now have "a*cd"
sb.deleteCharAt(i-1); // We now have "acd"...wait, we need to delete c too!
```

Another problem is that you are modifying the string builder when you are iterating through it. This is a bad idea, because you will have the wrong indices! Considering the following:

```
// We execute this on "ab*cd*ef", expecting "af".
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) { // length = 8
    if (sb.charAt(i) + "" == "*") {
        // First execution, i = 2. Second, i = 5.
        sb.deleteCharAt(i-1);
        sb.deleteCharAt(i-1);
        sb.deleteCharAt(i-1);
        // After we executed the first time, we get that sb's length
        // is now 5! Wait, so next time when we try to delete the i-1 
        // character, we are removing...f? That cannot be right!
    }
}
```

Since this is a coding exercise, I've left the actual debugging to yourself. It is a learning process to figure out *why* things are the way they are! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to use the equals method  for comparing objects 
== checks if it is the same instance not if it has the same value
ie:

```
 (sb.charAt(i)+""=="*")
```

shoudl be

```
 ((sb.charAt(i)+"").equals("*"))
```

Also you should use the replace method of string
ie:

```
"abxxxcd".replace("xxx","");
```

I think * may be  interpreted as  a regular expression so you have to escape it using \ (Im not sure  you have to try it or read the javadoc)

Another think which could fix it is this:

```
 (sb.charAt(i)=='*')
```

'*' is interpreted as a character

Answer (score 0):

What about a solution like that?

```
package eu.duernau.stackoverflow;

public class Sov33355763 {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        String s = deleteS("aba*b");
        System.out.println(s);
        s = deleteS("ab*ab");
        System.out.println(s);
        s = deleteS("ab*cd*ef*ghij*");
        System.out.println(s);
        s = deleteS("0*ab*cd*ef*ghij*");
        System.out.println(s);
        s = deleteS("****acd****");
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    private static String deleteS(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        int lastStarPosition;
        do {
            lastStarPosition = sb.lastIndexOf("*");            
            if (lastStarPosition > 1 && lastStarPosition + 1 < sb.length()) {
                sb.replace(lastStarPosition - 1, lastStarPosition + 2, "");
            } else {
                if (lastStarPosition + 1 == sb.length()) {
                    sb.replace(lastStarPosition - 1, lastStarPosition + 1, "");
                } else {
                    if (lastStarPosition > 0) {
                        sb.replace(lastStarPosition - 1, lastStarPosition + 2, "");
                    } else {
                        if (lastStarPosition > -1) {
                            sb.replace(lastStarPosition, lastStarPosition + 2, "");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (lastStarPosition > -1);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

produces

```
ab
ab
ahi
hi
d
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last one produce 'c' ?

Answer (score 0):

I only see this happening with [Regular Expressions](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html):

Code:

```
String pattern1 = ".?[*]+.?";
s = s.replaceAll(pattern1, "");
```